# How, if at all, does the behavior of a parallel plate capacitor change in the presence of a magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, capacitance

I'm an AP physics student curious about magnetism and my teacher couldn't answer this question. We already learned about velocity selectors, so I know that, when the plates of the capacitor are in the XZ plane and the magnetic field is in the Y or Z direction, there is no change in capacitance. What would happen if the magnetic field were in the X direction? Would the plates conduct the magnetic flux? Would there be a change in capacitance or any induced current? Thank you for your response.

Comment: Please explain the question in detail

Comment: A little mistyping? For capacitor in XZ plane there is not difference for a magnetic field in the directions **X** an Z. I'm curious about experimental results. In my understanding any magnetic field - no matter from which direction - has to reduce the capacitance of the capacitor.

Answer (score 0):

What 'behaviour' are you asking about?

Magnetic fields only affect moving charges.  If the charge on the capacitor is not changing, the magnetic field has no effect, regardless of whatever direction it is in.  No charges cross the space between the capacitor plates.  Perhaps you are thinking of a situation where charged particles are fired into the space between the plates of the capacitor, where there are crossed electric and magnetic fields.